# Regex for arithmetic expression

Tags: java, regex

The regex `-?\d+ [+|-|*|/] -?\d+` matches expression `1 + 3` without any problems also `1 + -2` without any problems, but I don't know why it does not match `1 - 2`. Could you explaing why it does not match the `-` char correctly?

By my regex I wanted to achieve:

- optional - at the beginning
- string of digits
- whitespace then operator then whitespace
- optional - before second stringof digits

Comment: escape the '-' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `-` unescaped in the middle of a character class creates a range. You can escape it or move it to the start or end of the character class. You also don't need/want the `|`s I'd guess.

You currently make a range between `|` and `|` which doesn't really make sense. You also could just use grouping instead of a character class.

```
(\+|-|\*|/)
```

With this approach the `+` and `*` need to be escaped because they are quantifiers when outside a character class.

Comment: Thanks to you I was able to make it work, thank you.

Comment: i think your answer is more clear than my answer you deserve the +1